# Cannot link my Azure DevOps Organization to my AAD tenant

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to connect my Azure DevOps Organization to my Azure AD Tenant. I'm the only user in both. I connect to both using my personal microsoft (@outlook.com) account. However, when I'm trying to link my DevOps orga to my Azure AD Tenant, Azure DevOps doesn't see me as a member of the Azure AD Tenant that I'm trying to connect to, even though I'm connected in Azure with the same Microsoft account that I use on Azure DevOps... I'm following the steps mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/connect-organization-to-azure-ad?view=azure-devops).

Below pic shows the error message I'm getting while trying to connect my Azure DevOps orga to my Default Azure AD Tenant :

[image: access error]

Here, you can see that I'm connected in my Azure AD Tenant with the same Microsoft account that in the previous picture :

[image: azure login]
[image: tenant]

Comment: Probably the simplest way to fix it is to create a temporary user in your AAD who isn't an MSA, but a pure AAD user, add that user to your Azure DevOps org in the Project Collection Admin group. Sign in with that user to confirm access. The kick your MSA user from the account, do the AAD connection, re-add your MSA user, add them back as collection admin, optionally delete your temporary user.

Comment: Jesse, I was able to connect using your method, but I lost the subscriptions I used with my @outlook.com account. I don't know what this black magic is. Both have the same domain and directory. I put the newly created account as Global Administrator but he cannot see the subscriptions!

Comment: Azure DevOps logs you on with a MSA identity. In AAD you log on with an MSA identity wrapped in an AAD identity. To Azure DevOps those are 2 different identifies, since undoer the hood they have a different UPN (unique principal name). It's all super confusing.

Comment: It's even more fun when your MSA is guest in multiple AAD Tennants. Ask me how I know ;).

Answer (score 1):

Tried to do the same where only one member who is the only admin is present in the azure AD tenant.But could successfully connect to azure devops.

Please make sure you are connecting already existed AAD tenant and then creating connection. check if admin permissions are given .

I had these roles assigned .

[image]

I had guest user access same as member access

[image]

[image]

Could smoothly connect without any warnings to the same domain as that of azure ad.
[image]

---

I tried to reproduce the issue and so tried connect with the other tenant /directory and got the error similar to yours which is not your case as you mentioned you have same directory domain.

[image]

So in your case , please close all other tabs and signin to only the required tenant both in azure ad and also in azure devops.

Please check the access permissions for this organization, if the organization is denied access for external access.
See [Access via Azure AD FAQs | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/faq-azure-access?view=azure-devops#q---why-don-t-i-see-my-organization-in-the-azure-portal-) which can guide to troubleshoot your error cause and it says to have co-admin or service admin permissions.

Also please take the points by  @jessehouwing  in the comments into consideration , if issue is still there :Create a new Global Admin user account in AAD,Add this user to the DevOps organisation and set as owner and give  Project Collection Administrators permission,Remove that domain from the DevOps org and Re-add to the org and re-assign as the owner.

Else it might be some issue with the default directory permissions. You may contact  and report a problem in [https://developercommunity](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html).

Comment: Thank you, I just answered to Jesse. I'm still not clear about the why of this behavior. Both accounts are on the same domain and directory.